# HttpResponseRedirect does not call another view

Tags: django

There are two separated views in my app, and I try one calling one view from the other by using HttpResponseRedirect, but it does not work at all. It still in the same page and no redirection. Can anyone help me figure out where causes errors?

in my view.py

```
def viewStore(request):
    if request.POST:
        if request.POST.get('delete_selected'):
            id = int(request.POST.get('check'))
            HttpResponseRedirect('/dataInfo/store_view/delete/%d/' %id)
    view_store = Store.objects.all()
    context = {'view_store': view_store}
    return render(request, 'dataInfo/store_view.html', context)

def deleteStore(request):
    if request.POST.get('delete_selected'):
        Store.objects.filter(pk__in=request.POST.get('check')).delete()
    HttpResponseRedirect('/dataInfo/store_view/')
```

In my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^store_view/$', views.viewStore, name='viewStore'),
url(r'^add_store/$', views.addStore, name='addStore'),
url(r'^thanks/$', views.thanks, name='thanks'),
url(r'^store_view/delete/(\d+)/$', views.deleteStore, name='deleteStore'),
]
```

Comment: If you have another question then you should raise it as a new question instead of editing your question into a new one

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Actually they are the same issue.

Comment: They are similar, but they aren't the same issue, the one you changed it to was about an error that you get when doing the redirection, your (original) question, was that it wasn't redirecting at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when your browser sends a POST request and receives a redirect, it will follow the redirect with a GET request.

- You POST to `viewStore`.
- `viewStore` redirects you to the `deleteStore` view
- Your browser GETs the `deleteStore` view
- `deleteStore` does not delete because it's a GET request, then redirects you to the `viewStore`

You should change the form in your template so that it posts directly to the `deleteStore` view.

Answer (score 1):

you must to **return** the `HttpResponseRedirect`. That is your error

Answer (score 0):

You never return the responses, you just create them. Simply `return` the responses.

```
def viewStore(request):
    if request.POST:
        if request.POST.get('delete_selected'):
            id = int(request.POST.get('check'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/dataInfo/store_view/delete/%d/' %id)
    view_store = Store.objects.all()
    context = {'view_store': view_store}
    return render(request, 'dataInfo/store_view.html', context)

def deleteStore(request):
    if request.POST.get('delete_selected'):
        Store.objects.filter(pk__in=request.POST.get('check')).delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/dataInfo/store_view/')
```